# Move the row and columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to change table rows and columns using sql, without using any pointer in Sqlserver or any other function. ex:

I have these data on table:

```
h1 | h2 | h3 | date                     
1    2    3     d1  
4    5    6     D2
```

I want to replace them and convert to this:

```
h value | date
1          d1
2          d1
3          d1
4          D2
5          D2
6          D2
```

Any solution?

Comment: Is it Sql server or Mysql ? Your tags and question description are contradictory

Comment: can you provide a sample query that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT h_value, date
FROM
(    
SELECT h1 AS h_value, date
    FROM your_table

    UNION

    SELECT h2 AS h_value, date
    FROM your_table

    UNION

    SELECT h3 AS h_value, date
    FROM your_table
)
ORDER BY h_value
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT h1 AS h_value, date FROM [table] UNION ALL
SELECT h2 AS h_value, date FROM [table] UNION ALL
SELECT h3 AS h_value, date FROM [table]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
create table table_new as 
select h1 as "h value",date from table
union all
select h2,date from table
union all
select h3,date from table
```